# Exact tape recording format for SVI-318/328 computers

Tags: cassette-tape, data-preservation

I'm looking for the exact tape data format of old SVI-318/328 computers, some kind of whitepapers explaining it.

I've obtained several information from a real tape, but I don't known if the infered rules are correct, if exists any variants, the correct bauds...

**EDIT:**

Empirically taken from a WAV file the format is:

---

The bits are codified like this:

- 0: 4 pulses at ~2400 Hz
- 1: 4 pulses at ~4800 Hz

Each data block have a pilot tone followed by the data without a pause between them.

The pilot can be codified like 199 bytes with value *0xAA* + 1 byte with value *0xFF*. These bytes don't have leading or trailing bits and are in MSb format.

And data come codified not using leading bits, and one 0 valued trailing bit. They are also using MSb.

---

What I need is a confirmation of this coding or not in case there is something missing or not accurate.

Comment: Because the SVI line is closely related to MSX which uses CUTS, maybe SVI does also. There's a paper linked from another question here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/cassette-tape-storage-formats/8543

Comment: Yes, that isn't the problem. SVI use KCS, like MSX do too. But the pulses codification of pilot/bits/bytes/control bits differs.

Comment: The things you say definitely sound likely, though possibly not the codification of the pilot tone for purely practical purposes — a lot of people would start the computer saving, then start the tape recording, cutting off the start of the pilot tone. And `0xaa` or `0x55` are very common sync patterns after a pilot tone because of the bit patterns. Though start bits are more common that stop bits so that's a bit of a surprise. Agreed that somebody definitely needs to unturf a manual on this.

Comment: @Tommy, that you say about start bits is interesting... Maybe the trailing bit I detected is the leading of the next byte.

Comment: Did you find this page? https://wiki.kasettilamerit.fi/wiki/index.php/Spectravideo - it seems to be on a small Finnish wiki whose title translates to "cassette lamers", but the tape format page itself is in English.

Comment: Thanks @hippietrail, looks like what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any technical manual:

- [SviWav2Cas](https://web.archive.org/web/20120810012024/http://home.student.uu.se/jowi4905/svi/#SWC) comes with source to decode sampled SVI3x8 tapes.
- [openMSX](https://openmsx.org/) can emulate the SVI machines and creates WAV files from `SAVE`/`BSAVE` that SviWav2Cas seems to understand.

Maybe save known data from openMSX in SVI mode (say a 1024 zero bytes, or 1024 &hFF bytes) and analyze the WAV files it produces?

*(the CAS files from SviWav2Cas don't appear to work with openMSX, though)*

Comment: Sure, that is what I did. But it depends on how faithful that software is. You can use too my conversor from SVI CAS to TSX files and use it with OpenMSX_TSX fork: https://github.com/nataliapc/MSX_devs/tree/master/TSXphpclass

Comment: Sounds like you're already doing what you can, then. Developer information seems to be thin on the ground for this almost-but-not-quite-MSX machine